# How to work with Linq in Composite c1 cms?

Tags: asp.net, linq, content-management-system, c1-cms

I am using composite c1 cms and i working with user control but when i am trying to access database via dbml file i am getting an error of importing namespaces. But there is no .cs file in this CMS, So can any one tell me how to work with linq in composite c1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the documentation found [here](http://docs.composite.net/Data/AccessingDataWithCSharp/How-to-Query-Data-Using-LINQ)

You can just place your code at App_Code or compile your code into an assembly and place that into the bin folder. Or use [Razor](http://docs.composite.net/ASP-NET/Razor) or [User Control Functions](http://docs.composite.net/Packages/Contribution/User-Control-Functions).

Comment: You can also compile your code into an assembly and put it into the bin folder